# User login fails when using password encoding in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, password-encryption

I am using Spring `StandardPasswordEncoder` to encode password before inserting into database. But when trying to login with same password I am getting an invalid password error. Not sure what is wrong. Below is the code.

security configuration:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="authMgr">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="passwordEncoder   class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
</bean>
```

Service layer(password encoding before passing data to data access layer)

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newAccountDetails.getPassword()));
userDataAccess.createUser(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the recommendation [How to use new PasswordEncoder from Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444258/how-to-use-new-passwordencoder-from-spring-security) applies. See the accepted answer there for a good explanation.

I'd modify the suggested code in one of the answers to the following to better fit your current setup:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="authMgr">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="passwordEncoder class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem though I had authorities-by-username-query set on my authentication provider.
Even though I had the correct security configuration, authentication failed with invalid username/password **when the user had no authority in my database** . The error message was misleading.