# Password encoding and decoding using Spring Security, Spring Boot and MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, password-encryption

I use the mentions software stack above and I need to encrypt password before save into database. I also need to decrypt password because when someone will change password he she needs to give in the old password and then the new onw twice and I need to check the old password.
I have searched a lot but I still not sure what is the right way to do this.
I have found this link [Encrypting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444258/how-to-use-new-passwordencoder-from-spring-security) but are there other hints to do this?
I also not sure if maybe MongoDB provides something to protect passwords.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*First read [Steven Carlson´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35238919/280244) about password hashing.*

The good thing is that Spring Security will do this for you. Spring Security 3.2 introduced the new [`org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html) interface and some implementations: [`BCryptPasswordEncoder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html), [`StandardPasswordEncoder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html) (and `NoOpPasswordEncoder`).

Important: Do not confuse `org.springframework.security.`**`crypto.password`**`.PasswordEncoder` with the old deprecated `org.springframework.security.`**`authentication.encoding`**`.PasswordEncoder`

The interface (and therefore the implementations) has the two methods you need:

- `public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword)`
- `public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)`

I recommend to use [`org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html).
The `BCryptPasswordEncoder` (in contrast to the `StandardPasswordEncoder`) use an salt that is different for each password (but not global like the one from `StandardPasswordEncoder`). When you encode a raw password (`public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword)`) then the returned encoded password is not just the encoded password, it also contains some meta information about the used hash-algorithm, the used salt and of course the encoded password.

Comment: Thank you for adding the Spring info as I am not familiar with that product :)

Comment: How can I fetch the meta information as you mentioned, for example the used salt ?

Comment: In case of `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, the meta information is just the salt: Have a look at `BCrypt.hashpw(String password, String salt)`. The parameter named `salt` is the crypted old password. And the code in that method "read" the salt from the password

Answer (score 24):

You should not be "encrypting" the password at all.  I know this sounds counter-intuitive.  But there is zero reason your system should need to decrypt the password.  To do so would open your database to a hacker, because if you store your decryption password in your codes/server a hacker can steal that information.

The correct process is to `hash` the password.  A hash is a one-way (cannot be decypted back to the original text) process.  The current standard would be to use SHA256 to hash your password.  Here is a basic flow-chart:

1. Take user submitted password.  Example password "mypass" would hash out to `ea71c25a7a602246b4c39824b855678894a96f43bb9b71319c39700a1e045222`
2. Store this hash (`ea71c25a7a602246b4c39824b855678894a96f43bb9b71319c39700a1e045222`) in your database.

When a user logs in you take the password he just submitted and hash it.  If he enters the same password it will hash out to the same value in your database.

When a user goes to change passwords you hash the "enter your old password" to verify the old password still matches, if it does you hash the "enter your new password" and save it.

One thing I did not mention in my example is `salt`.  This is something you must use in your system as it protects your data from `rainbow table` exploits.  But that is for another discussion.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi @Steven, you mentioned in your answer that for comparing the password just take the password and hash it and compare ? Usually this comparison will be like `select * from users where email=? and password=?`, since this hashed password will be different, how this matching works ?

Comment: Ok, If I understood you correctly, we will fetch user with email id and then uses the `match` to match the password with encoded and plain text.